# Weird behavior of jQuery UI's sortable function: is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery UI's sortable for a project of mine. Now, everything is fine until the update method is called. The code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu_sections').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var new_order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
        }
    });
});
```

The sortable works exactly as it should, the items are sortable. But, when I change the place of one item, the update event is called, and I get the following message in Firebug's console:

```
$("#menu_sections").sortable is not a function
var new_order = $('#menu_sections').sortable('serialize');
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: If you found the solution you can self-answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define a pointer in outer scope.

```
update: function(event, ui) {
    var new_order = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    }
```

in your update callback, "this" doesn't point to the "this" you want.

Comment: I have tried $('#menu_sections').sortable('serialize') also, they same thing happened.

Comment: i am sorry for my answer. princibally, there is nothing wrong with your code, at least in the piece you are exposing.